# What is the difference between describe and it in Jest?

Tags: jasmine, jestjs

When writing a unit test in `Jest` or `Jasmine` when do you use `describe`?

When do you use `it`?

I usually do

```js
describe('my beverage', () => {
  test('is delicious', () => {
  });
});
```

When is it time for a new `describe` or a new `it`?

Answer (score 258):

`describe` breaks your test suite into components. Depending on your test strategy, you might have a describe for each function in your class, each module of your plugin, or each user-facing piece of functionality.

You can also nest describes to further subdivide the suite.

`it` is where you perform individual tests. You should be able to describe each test like a little sentence, such as "it calculates the area when the radius is set". You shouldn't be able to subdivide tests further-- if you feel like you need to, use `describe` instead.

```js
describe('Circle class', function() {
  describe('area is calculated when', function() {
    it('sets the radius', function() { ... });
    it('sets the diameter', function() { ... });
    it('sets the circumference', function() { ... });
  });
});
```

Comment: I love this wording style, it reads like plain English.

Answer (score 111):

As I mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59877184/12666332), `describe` is for grouping, `it` is for testing.

As the jest docs says, `test` and `it` are the same:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testname-fn-timeout

> **test(name, fn, timeout)**
>
> Also under the alias: it(name, fn, timeout)

and `describe` is just for when you prefer your tests to be organized into groups:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#describename-fn

> describe(name, fn)

`describe(name, fn)` creates a block that groups together several related tests. For example, if you have a `myBeverage` object that is supposed to be delicious but not sour, you could test it with:

```js
const myBeverage = {
  delicious: true,
  sour: false,
};

describe('my beverage', () => {
  test('is delicious', () => {
    expect(myBeverage.delicious).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('is not sour', () => {
    expect(myBeverage.sour).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

This isn't required - you can write the test blocks directly at the top level. But this can be handy if you prefer your tests to be organized into groups.

Answer (score 4):

I consider this more from the impact on the test output. By using describe or multiple levels of describe you can group your output for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Think simple that `describe` is group and `it` or `test` is really unit test.

So, `describe` can be nested in `describe` but `it` isn't.