# What is the difference between 'it' and 'test' in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have two tests in my test group. One of the tests use `it` and the other one uses `test`. Both of them seem to be working very similarly. What is the difference between them?

```
describe('updateAll', () => {
  it('no force', () => {
    return updateAll(TableName, ["fileName"], {compandId: "test"})
        .then(updatedItems => {
          let undefinedCount = 0;
          for (let item of updatedItems) {
            undefinedCount += item === undefined ? 1 : 0;
          }
          // console.log("result", result);
          expect(undefinedCount).toBe(updatedItems.length);
        })
  });

  test('force update', () => {
    return updateAll(TableName, ["fileName"], {compandId: "test"}, true)
        .then(updatedItems => {
          let undefinedCount = 0;
          for (let item of updatedItems) {
            undefinedCount += item === undefined ? 1 : 0;
          }
          // console.log("result", result);
          expect(undefinedCount).toBe(0);
        })
  });
});
```

---

**Update - Nov 2022:**

It seems that `test` and `it` is interchangeable according to [the official API of Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html). As @gwildu described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072272/4056509), you should choose one over the other for the sake of **readability**.

Comment: `it` might just be there for familiarity and migration from other frameworks.

Comment: there is no difference.  The documentation clearly states `test` is under the alias `it`.

Comment: Their logic is similar, but their semantics differ when it comes to reading

Answer (score 916, accepted):

The [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/api) state [`it` is an alias of `test`](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout). So they are exactly the same from a functional point of view. They exist both to enable to make a readable English sentence from your test.

Answer (score 263):

They do the same thing, but their names are different and with that their interaction with the name of the test.

***`test`***

What you write:

```js
describe('yourModule', () => {
  test('if it does this thing', () => {});
  test('if it does the other thing', () => {});
});
```

What you get if something fails:

```sh
yourModule > if it does this thing
```

***`it`***

What you write:

```js
describe('yourModule', () => {
  it('should do this thing', () => {});
  it('should do the other thing', () => {});
});
```

What you get if something fails:

```sh
yourModule > should do this thing
```

So it's about readability not about functionality.

In my opinion, `it` really has a point when it comes to read the result of a failing test that you haven't written yourself. It helps to faster understand what the test is about.

Some developer also shorten the `Should do this thing` to `Does this thing` which is a bit shorter and also fits semantically to the `it` notation.

Comment: some also prefer `it('does this thing', () => {})` instead of  `it('should do this thing', () => {}` as its shorter

Comment: Alternatively, `test('thing should do x')` may be preferred over `it('Should do X')` as `it` is often vague.

Comment: @mikemaccana if you write `test('thing should do x')` you don't have a semantically correct sentence. The Idea behind those notation I think is really, that you can read a test in a sentence as you would speak. Same if you write `test('Does this thing')`. Of course you can do that, but the notation semantically would actually fit to the `it` notation

Comment: `test('thing should do x')` is literally 'testing that thing should do X' - so the test reads as one would speak. `test('thing does x')` is also fine.

Answer (score 45):

As the other answers have clarified, they do the same thing.

I believe the two are offered to allow for either 1) "[RSpec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSpec)" style tests like:

```
const myBeverage = {
  delicious: true,
  sour: false,
};

describe('my beverage', () => {
  it('is delicious', () => {
    expect(myBeverage.delicious).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('is not sour', () => {
    expect(myBeverage.sour).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

or 2) "[xUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit)" style tests like:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

test('sum adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Documentation:

- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api.html#describename-fn
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api.html#testname-fn-timeout

Answer (score 12):

As the jest documentation says, they are the same:
[it alias](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testname-fn-timeout)

> **test(name, fn, timeout)**
>
> Also under the alias: it(name, fn, timeout)

And `describe` is just for when you prefer your tests to be organized into groups:
[describe](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#describename-fn)

> describe(name, fn)

`describe(name, fn)` creates a block that groups together several related tests. For example, if you have a myBeverage object that is supposed to be delicious but not sour, you could test it with:

```
const myBeverage = {
  delicious: true,
  sour: false,
};

describe('my beverage', () => {
  test('is delicious', () => {
    expect(myBeverage.delicious).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('is not sour', () => {
    expect(myBeverage.sour).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

This isn't required - you can write the test blocks directly at the top level. But this can be handy if you prefer your tests to be organized into groups.

Answer (score 9):

You could replace `it()` with `xit()` to temporarily exclude a test from being executed; using `it()` and `xit()` is more eloquent than using `test()` and `xit()`.

see [Focusing and Excluding Tests](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#focusing-and-excluding-tests)

Comment: There is a "xtest" too, so both are pretty much alike.

Comment: `xit()` is also shorter

Comment: And much less clear.

Answer (score 4):

The following is an excerpt from the document：[link](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout)

> `test(name, fn, timeout)`
>
> Also under the alias: `it(name, fn, timeout)`
>
> All you need in a test file is the test method which runs a test. For
> example, let's say there's a function `inchesOfRain()` that should be
> zero. Your whole test could be: ......

Answer (score -5):

`const request = require('supertest');` 
`const app =  require('../app')`
`const {it, describe} = require('@jest/globals');`
`const { sequelize } = require('../models');`
`const {hash} = require('../helpers/bcrypt')`

`beforeAll(async ()=>{ await sequelize.queryInterface.bulkInsert('Customers', [{ username: "nikita", email:"nikita@mail.com", password: hash("nikita"), createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date() }]) })`

`afterAll(async ()=>{ await sequelize.queryInterface.bulkDelete('Customers', null, { truncate: true, cascade: true, restartIdentity: true }) })`

`describe('POST /customers/register', () => { it('should response with status 201', async ()=> { let customer = { username: "hello" , email:"hello@mail.com", password:"hello", } let response = await request(app) .post('/customers/register').send(customer) expect(response.status).toBe(201) // console.log(response.body, 'ini ressss') expect(response.body).toEqual({ message: "Input data Customer succeed", id: expect.any(Number), email: expect.any(String) }) });` 
`it('should response with status 400', async()=>{ let customer = { username: "hello", password:"hello" } let response =  await request(app) .post('/customers/register').send(customer) expect(response.status).toBe(400) // console.log(response.body,"<<<"); expect(response.body[0].message).toBe('Please input email') })`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

```
`const request = require('supertest');`
`const app =  require('../app')`
`const {it, describe} = require('@jest/globals');`
`const { sequelize, Category, User, News , Customer, Bookmark} = require('../models');`
`const {hash} = require('../helpers/bcrypt');`
`const news = require('../models/news');`
`const {queryInterface} = sequelize`


`beforeAll(async()=>{

    let userData = require("../data/user.json")
    userData.forEach(el => {
        el.password = hash(el.password)
        el.createdAt = new Date()
        el.updatedAt = new Date()
    });`

`afterAll(async ()=>{
    await Bookmark.destroy({
        truncate: true,
        cascade: true,
        restartIdentity: true
    })`

`describe('GET /customers/news', () => {
    it("should response with status 200 1", async () => {
        let response = await request(app)
        .get('/customers/news')
        // .set({access_token})
        // console.log(response.body, "<<<<NEWS NIhH");
        expect(response.status).toBe(200)
        expect(response.body).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
    })`

`it("should response with status 200 2", async()=>{
    let response = await request(app)
    .get('/customers/news?filter=1,2')
    expect(response.status).toBe(200)
    expect(response.body).toBeInstanceOf(Array)
})`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -20):

Jest haven't mentioned why they have two versions for the exact same functionality.

My guess is, it's only for convention. `test` is for unit tests, and `it` is for integration tests.

Answer (score -37):

They are the same thing. I am using TypeScript as the programming language, and when I look into the definition file from the Jest package source code from /@types/jest/index.d.ts, I can see the following code.

Obviously, there are lots of different names of 'test', and you can use any of them.

```html
declare var beforeAll: jest.Lifecycle;
declare var beforeEach: jest.Lifecycle;
declare var afterAll: jest.Lifecycle;
declare var afterEach: jest.Lifecycle;
declare var describe: jest.Describe;
declare var fdescribe: jest.Describe;
declare var xdescribe: jest.Describe;
declare var it: jest.It;
declare var fit: jest.It;
declare var xit: jest.It;
declare var test: jest.It;
declare var xtest: jest.It;
```

Comment: The code you show does not indicate that `it` and `test` are the same thing. It just means that their type is the same. I do not think that `beforeAll` and `afterAll` are the same thing even though their type is the same.

Comment: `xit and xtest` skips the tests, `it, fit, test` are to execute tests.  Thanks for your answer.