# Difference between describe() and test() in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have found that `expect()` works within `describe()`. So the function `test()` is not necessary, if I see it right. Do I see it right?

In other words, is it enough to write that:

```
const sum = require('./sum');

describe('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Or does that bring advantages:

```
const sum = require('./sum');

describe('test sum', () => {
  test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: Try a _failing_ test and see where it gets you. A single test isn't a good example because you can just use `test` (or `it`) _without_ `describe`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between describe and it in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055287/what-is-the-difference-between-describe-and-it-in-jest)

Answer (score 4):

> `describe(name, fn)` creates a block that groups together several
> related tests.

Detail: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describename-fn

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know, if it is fine, to use my fist example without the test()-methode, because it works - it also show failing tests.

Comment: @astridx I never try this before and I wouldn't do this. If you only want one layer, use `test` instead of `describe`. I think the test report might get wrong if you use your first example